# After installation of website it changes Application Pool of web application that follows it.

Tags: iis, windows-installer, installshield, application-pool

I have InstallShield (IS) Basic MSI project, that creates Application Pool and installs web application on IIS under existing website.

On IIS default website is stopped and different website named WebApps using port 80 is running it uses AppPool1. Under WebApps we have several applications that use different App Pool for themselves for example AppPool2, AppPool3. When I install new application under WebApps and set its App Pool to newly created AppPool4 some applications App Pool changes to ASP.NET v4.0 AppPool1.

You can see my Application Pool and Web App settings below from IS.
[image]

[image]
Does anyone know why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

Issue was with Web App .NET Framework version was set to v4.0 and this would cause all the Web Apps under Website to be set to use .NET Framework v4.0